# can't get jQuery .load to load content into div

Tags: jquery, load

I have a list as such :

```
<ul id="yearMenu">
  <li>Select a year</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2010PR.html">2010</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2009PR.html">2009</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2008PR.html">2008</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2007PR.html">2007</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2006PR.html">2006</a> |</li>
  <li><a href="AJAX/2005PR.html">2005</a></li>
</ul>
```

below that in another container is this div:

```
<div id="tableContent" class="tabWrapp"></div>
```

and the following load function:

```
$("#ul#yearMenu li a").click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#tableContent").load(href + " #tableContent ", function() {
    //need to do something here?
  });
});
```

but all links open in another page. what do I need to do to get this to load in the #tableContent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul#yearMenu li a").click(function(event) {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(href, function(data) {
    $('#tableContent').html(data);
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: initially I used the above, adding return false(); However the .load didn't work in IE. I tried yours using the .get and it worked perfectly. Thanks man.

Comment: after further testing I get this to work in all browsers, except Safari, it doesn't load any scripts with the page being loaded. I'm loading a table that uses .jquery tablesorter and pagination plug in. When I click a link to load a different table, no JS functionality again this is only in Safari. I have placed the links to the JS on both the main page and the AJAX page, as well with the functions. any ideas?

Comment: hmm maybe you can put the link to your page here? seeing the code may be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

```
return false;
```

to the end of your "click" handler. Without that, the default action of each `<a>` tag will be taken.

It would be even better (safer, some would say) to call `.preventDefault()` on the event object:

```
$('#whatever').click(function(evt) {
  // ...
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

That'll allow the event to bubble but prevent the `<a>` default action.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use href to store the link. use a custom attr like 'data-link="http://link.com"'

```
<li><a data-link="AJAX/2010PR.html">2010</a> |</li>
```

so, when you click nothing will happen.

In your javascript code, you get the link using:

```
$(selector).attr("data-link");
```

Then to makeup the A as link, use some css.

It's just a alternative way, but with "preventDefault()" or "return false", also works well.

Comment: This will work, but it might cause crawlers/spiders to miss the links, which for some sites would be a problem.